# Insert into View giving Insufficient Privileges error while compiling package

Tags: oracle, view, insert, privileges, oracle19c

**View :**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_XYZ AS
SELECT "TRN_REF_NO","ESN","COMPONENT","AMOUNT","CURRENCY","WAIVER","CHG_DESC"
FROM 
( WITH DATA AS
( SELECT LEVEL L FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5 )
  SELECT TRN_REF_NO,1 "ESN",'CHG_AMT_'||L "COMPONENT",
         DECODE(L,1,CHG_AMT,2,CHG_AMT_1,3,CHG_AMT_2,4,CHG_AMT_3,5,CHG_AMT_4) "AMOUNT",
         DECODE(L,1,CHG_CCY,2,CHG_CCY_1,3,CHG_CCY_2,4,CHG_CCY_3,5,CHG_CCY_4) "CURRENCY",
         DECODE(L,1,WAIVER,2,WAIVER1,3,WAIVER2,4,WAIVER3,5,WAIVER4) "WAIVER",
         DECODE(L,1,CHG_DESC,2,CHG_DESC1,3,CHG_DESC2,4,CHG_DESC3,5,CHG_DESC4) "CHG_DESC"
    FROM DATA
    JOIN tb_abc
      ON NVL(DECODE(L,1,CHG_AMT,2,CHG_AMT_1,3,CHG_AMT_2,4,CHG_AMT_3,5,CHG_AMT_4),'-1') <> -1
 ORDER BY TRN_REF_NO );
```

**Error in Package Body :**
**Line :**

> INSERT INTO vw_XYZ
> **Error facing :**
> Compilation errors for PACKAGE BODY
>
> Error: PL/SQL: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Please note :
We are facing this issue in **19c** Database only. In **12c** Database version it compiles successfully

Comment: it's not possible to insert something through a join view including ver.12c.

Comment: Thank you @BarbarosÖzhan ... But in 12c version... My package gets successfully compiled. Can you please elaborate

Comment: you're welcome. Are you sure that you didn't attempt to insert into tb_abc as in your first case ? Btw, the error seems related with missing privilege. Indeed even if you have that view in the current schema, you cannot insert through it.

Comment: Yes @BarbarosÖzhan, I'm sure we are doing exactly same thing in both the versions because we just imported everything from 12c version to 19c version. No manual interaction was there. The view is in the same schema as of the package.

Comment: It is about *privileges*. User on 19c doesn't have all privileges it had on 12c. That might be related to other users in that database, e.g. if vw_XYZ is owned by someone else, not *you* (user who compiles that package).